# Django Keycloak Integration

Tags: python, django, keycloak

I am trying to integrate Keycloak (single sign on) in Django framework. There are couple of packages I found online, however, none of them are working as per the expectation.

Is there any documentation or example source codes from which I can get the help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/drf-keycloak-auth/, this one is working 100%

Answer (score 2):

Use [Django OAuth Toolkit](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-oauth-toolkit/) you can find the guide from [Django OAuth Toolkitguide](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-oauth-toolkit/). check the [OIDC](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/oidc.html) section